# "resource temporarily unavailable" in recv in socket programming

Tags: linux, sockets

I want to read and write over Wanpipe driver (a network device driver for Sangoma cards) via socket programming but i get this message error: "resource temporarily unavailable". The card is working and i see it send and receive packets in ifconfig. I have included my code and would be very pleased if somebody help me in this. 
A related question: I set the socket to blocking mode but the recv message does not block? how could i block the recv?

```
int main(void)
{
   int sd;
   int buflen=WP_HEADER + MAX_PACKET;
   char buf[buflen];
   struct wan_sockaddr_ll sa;
   sd = socket(AF_WANPIPE, SOCK_RAW,0);

   if (sd < 0) /* if socket failed to initialize, exit */
   {
      perror("Error Creating Socket");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Socket Descriptor:%d\n",sd);
   memset(&sa,0,sizeof(struct wan_sockaddr_ll));
   strncpy((char*)sa.sll_card,"wanpipe1",sizeof(sa.sl l_card));
   strncpy((char*)sa.sll_device,"w1g1",sizeof(sa.sll_ device)); 
   sa.sll_protocol = htons(PVC_PROT);
   sa.sll_family = AF_WANPIPE;

   if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa)) < 0)
   {
      perror("error bind failed");
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
   }

   int data=0;
   int ret=ioctl(sd,FIONBIO,&data);

   if (ret < 0) 
   {
      perror("ioctl error!");
      close(sd);
      return 1;
   }

   fd_set read_fds;
   struct timeval timeout;
   timeout.tv_sec = 10;
   timeout.tv_usec = 0;
   FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
   FD_SET(sd,&read_fds);

   if(select(sd+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout) < 0)
   {
      perror("select() error!");
      exit(1);
   }

   if (FD_ISSET(sd,&read_fds))
      printf("There is data for reading\n");
   else
      printf("There is no data for reading\n");*/

   // MSG_WAITALL | MSG_PEEK | MSG_OOB
   int r=recv(sd,buf,buflen,0);

   if (r < 0) 
   {
      perror("Wanpipe raw socket reading");
      close(sd);
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("\nNumber of bytes read into the buffer: %d",r);
   printf("\nThe read buffer: ");
   puts(buf);
   close(sd);
}
```

thank you in advance.